# Docker not mapping folders

Tags: docker, jenkins, devops

I am connected in a Docker container. In this container, when I execute:

```
sudo docker run --entrypoint bash  -it -v /home/jenkins/workspace/deployment:/app  myregistry.com/ansible-shade:2.2.1.0
```

I can see mapping is not happening between `/home/jenkins/workspace/deployment` and `/app`

In `/home/jenkins/workspace/deployment`, there is a lot of files, but in  `/app`, I can't see anything

Any idea why does it happen ?

Answer (score 0):

I found out what the problem,

My use case is that I work in a centOS that has all files, then I ssh a ubuntu that has no file and then in this ubuntu, I connect to docker container, so source path is from ubuntu not the docker image ( where files are )

The solution in that case is having files in the ubuntu vm so it can be mounted